# AWS S3: Howto maintain empty directory structure after deleting last file

Tags: amazon-s3

For the AWS SDK for Java library (used by `cognitect-labs/aws-api`), if I delete the last object in a "directory", I'd expect to be left with an empty directory.

https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/
https://github.com/cognitect-labs/aws-api

Instead, DeleteObject deletes the directory as well (not what I want). Is there a way to avoid this?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_DeleteObject.html

```
(require '[cognitect.aws.client.api :as aws])

;; Copying works fine
(aws/invoke aws/client
            {:op :CopyObject
             :request {:Bucket "bucket"
                       :CopySource "bucket/dirA/f1"
                       :Key "dirB/f1"}})

;; However, deleting removes f1 and dirA (if dirA is empty)
(aws/invoke aws/client
            {:op :DeleteObject
             :request {:Bucket "bucket"
                       :Key "dirA/f1"}})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible, because the folders you see in S3 are not really folders. It is organised as folders for easy. But it's not really folders.

Answer (score 0):

S3 is smart enough to know when a folder was created with an object. So when the object is deleted, the folder is deleted too. Otherwise you'd have empty folders dangling in the bucket.

However - when I was testing this, I found that if you created the folder *separately* before creating the objects in the folder, `DeleteObject` preserves the empty folder. This wasn't the case for [`DeleteObjects`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_DeleteObjects.html).